# Double Posting - Flag

Tags: discussion, flags

This morning I came  across a question by a [new user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5543330/casey-honaker) who was asking about password policy's. He posted one question 22 hours ago and another 13 minutes ago, both with the same text.

> Today I am trying to figure out how to do password rules and I have
>   been using the net accounts command; however, I have not found out how
>   to do password complexity from the cmd. I know how to use the local
>   security policies gui but I want to make it into a batch script. so my
>   question is :is the a cmd command or batch script that set password
>   complexity? any help would be appreciated

The duplicate flag says for questions that *already have an answer* so what would be the correct flag for this situation.

The questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633910/password-policy-batch-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614260/how-to-enable-password-complexity-from-the-command-line).

Comment: Duplicate is fine. If the questions are both from the exact same account, it bypasses the first one needing an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two posts are exact word-for-word copies by the same user (or even by different users), that's pretty easy for moderators to judge. That's one of the few cases where we don't mind getting a custom flag telling us that the two questions are duplicates. We can read and close those pretty quickly.

I've closed the older question as a duplicate of the newer, cleaned up one here.

For more common duplicate cases, you can still use a standard duplicate close vote or close flag on questions asked by the same user, even if neither question has an answer. You only can't do so if the questions are asked by different users and the target question lacks an answer.