# Double posted question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've just had a custom flag declined for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810020/calling-https-webservice-from-vba) where the OP actually stated themselves that they have another question open for the same issue.

[This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309866/double-posting-flag) implied that it was okay to raise the flag so I did, but the decline reason was

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Let me make this very clear. **I am not disputing the flag being declined, or the moderator's comment** - It makes perfect sense.

I have cast a close vote - but it looks like the post isn't really getting any attention and no-one else has voted (at the time of me posting this).

It might be pedantic - but one of my pet hates is when someone posts the same question again because they feel they didn't get enough attention or get a response quickly enough because it's duplicating the efforts of those that give their time for free to help others.

So my question is, what is the best course of action to take in the scenario? Just wait and hope that others pick up on this and cast close votes? Should there perhaps be a script or similar that can move such posts into a review queue if a certain percentage of the content is a verbatim copy?

Again, not disputing anything here - just looking for "best practice" as it were...

Comment: For maximum irony, you should have posted your meta question twice :)  Mod flags are not there to help with questions that should just simply be closed.  However there is the close votes chat room where you can ask for others to help get enough votes in to close the question in question quickly.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers

Comment: @JK. haha wish I had thought of that! Also didn't know about the chat room - will bear that one in mind for future reference. Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found out, you shouldn't have flagged this.

Once you've cast your close vote, sit back and wait. The close vote queue is BIG, so it may take some time before it gets closed, if ever.

However in this case it's debatable whether it should be closed as a duplicate of his first - the OP has used the exact same code block, but technically they have asked a subtly different question. The first question was *"fix my specific error for me"*, the second question is more *"how do I do it in general, here's a sample I've tried"*.

Now some would argue that the questions are close enough that today's should be closed, and someone with a dupehammer may go ahead and do it, or the meta effect might kick in. But in general you have to be patient and let the community do its work.

Comment: tbh - I forgot about the close queue altogether. I figured this would be the answer but thought it wouldn't hurt to ask, as it turns out I did in fact learn something as I wasn't aware of the chat room. Thanks for clarifying though :)