# Flagging for "Double Duped" Questions and Account

Tags: discussion

These questions wer not only identical duplicates, but the user accounts for these 2 questions are screaming duplicate accounts. I used my flags, but neither of the questions had answers tho.

Should I have? and should he have "double duped?" or may he?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588128/javascript-regex-is-not-working

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968593/javascript-regex-is-not-working

Comment: according to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310666/double-posted-question, I shouldn't have. However, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309866/double-posting-flag states that I should have.

Comment: I have dupe voted the questions, it is not forbidden to have two accounts as long as there is no cross voting across these accounts and based on what I see in the profile I don't think that happened much, if at all.

Comment: The average useful lifetime of an SO user account compares unfavorable to that of a mayfly.   Fairly likely he got question-banned given the voting on his questions on his old account, the workaround is very simple.  He did better with his new account so no real reason for the mods to do anything about it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you see someone posting an exact duplicate question from two different accounts, it's fine to let us know about that via a flag.

As Hans hints, it's usually done to evade a question ban, and I tend to delete accounts created for this reason. For some reason, I can't delete this account, despite it not having much to its name. I've at least marked the duplicates and will look into the accounts further.